# LINQ InvalidOperationException when making a query

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

Ok, last edit, promise:

With the following class:

```
public partial class MembershipModule : BaseConnection<MembershipModule>
{
    private const string AccessPrivilege = "Access";

    public bool Accessible()
    {
        return this.Privileges().Any(p => p.Name.Equals(AccessPrivilege));
    }

    public IQueryable<MembershipAction> Privileges()
    {
        var privileges = from p in LinqUtil.Context.MembershipModuleActions
                         where
                             p.MembershipModule.Id.Equals(this.Id) &&
                             p.MembershipRolePrivileges.Any(rp => rp.ModuleActionId.Equals(p.Id))
                         select p.MembershipAction;

        return privileges;
    }
}
```

Why does this work

```
    public static List<MembershipModule> Collection()
    {
        List<MembershipModule> collection = new List<MembershipModule>();

        if(!MembershipUser.Connected)
            return collection;

        foreach(MembershipModule m in LinqUtil.Context.MembershipModules)
        {
            if(m.Accessible())
                collection.Add(m);
        }

        return collection;
    }
```

While this doesn't?

```
    public static List<MembershipModule> Collection()
    {
        if(!MembershipUser.Connected)
            return new List<MembershipModule>();

        return LinqUtil.Context.MembershipModules.Where(m => m.Accessible()).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Your class name starts with an underscore and lowercase letter?  Ugh.  Please don't, it's not even CLS compliant to start a class name with an underscore let alone the fact that it's ugly.

Comment: yeah, I think I based that on aspnet membership tables, I already changed it, good advice =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks to me like you are trying to execute a linq to object operation and it is trying to convert it to a sql statement.

Keep in mind: If this were to succede, I expect that the sql related to the folowing call would happen once per MembershipModule:

```
 return this.Privileges().Any(p => p.Name.Equals(AccessPrivilege));
```

Have you tried skipping using the Accesible method, and hitting the Privileges collection directly? Something like this the code below. I have changed the return statement. This is the gist, may not be 100% correct:

```
public static List<MembershipModule> Collection()      
{      
    if(!MembershipUser.Connected)      
        return new List<MembershipModule>();      

    var mod = MembershipModule.SearchById(new Guid("b012d35f-6af1-47de-9e54-e5df957c07e1"));      

    var y = from p in LinqUtil.Context.MembershipModuleActions      
            where      
                p.MembershipModule.Id.Equals(mod.Id) &&      
                p.MembershipRolePrivileges.Any(rp => rp.ModuleActionId.Equals(p.Id))      
            select p.MembershipAction;      

    var u = y.Any(p => p.Name.Equals(AccessPrivilege));      

    return LinqUtil.Context.MembershipModules.Where(m => m.Privileges().Any(p => p.Name.Equals(AccessPrivilege)).ToList();  
}
```

Comment: Matter of fact I did try and I got this exception: Member access 'System.String Name' of 'Business.MembershipAction' not legal on type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Business.MembershipAction].   But I can't find a reason on earth why it would be 'illegal' doing so, Name is a varchar(35) that doesn't accept nulls...

Comment: just in case I just tried comparing Id instead of Name and I got the same result, not legal.

Comment: what is 'AccessPrivilege'? Is it an enum of yours, or should is be is a string?: (p => p.Name.Equals('AccessPrivilege')? If it is an enum: What is the access modifier?

Comment: it's right there on my post. private const string AccessPrivilege = "Access";

Comment: yes. There is is. right in fromt of me  :).  This is an odd error. Does it not like the var u= line or the return statement? or both?

Comment: u returns true... the return statement throws the 'illegal action' exception

Answer (score 0):

Could it have to do with a static method (`public static List<_membershipModule> Collection()`) of a class trying access instance members (`AccessPrivilege`)?

Comment: doesn't look like it has to do with this, check my edit to the question